# Selecting object with collection of objects from many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have three tables: `Athletes`, `Teams`, and `Team_Athletes`. `Team_Athletes` joins the other two tables in a many-to-many relationship. What I'm doing is querying the database to return an object with the Athlete and with a collection of Teams. I'm currently doing this with the following two queries:

```
   var query = (from a in db.Athletes
                join ta in db.Team_Athletes on a.Id equals ta.AthleteId
                join t in db.Teams on ta.TeamId equals t.Id
                where t.OrganizationId == organizationId 
                orderby a.LastName, a.FirstName
                select new
                {
                    Athlete = a,
                    Team = t
                }).ToArray();

   var result = from i in query
                group i by i.Athlete into g
                select new 
                {
                    Athlete = g.First().Athlete,
                    Teams = g.Select(i => i.Team).ToArray()
                };
```

I'd like to know how to combine the queries together if possible, but I can't come up with anything that works. Thoughts?

Comment: Which flavor of LINQ are you using? LINQ to SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use:

```
var query = from a in db.Athletes
            join ta in db.Team_Athletes on a.Id equals ta.AthleteId
            join t in db.Teams on ta.TeamId equals t.Id
            where t.OrganizationId == organizationId 
            orderby a.LastName, a.FirstName
            group t by a into g
            select new { Athlete = g.Key, Teams = g };
```

You could then iterate through the result, like so:

```
foreach (var entry in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Athlete: {0}", entry.Athlete);
    foreach (Team t in entry.Teams)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Team: {0}", t);
    }
}
```

Comment: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `...ToList[Team]` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" - exception thrown

Comment: you're right - drop the `ToList()` off your answer?